# Certain values for WHERE clause involving foreign key are slow

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, indexing, foreign-keys, rebuild

This query works:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[PROJECT_ID]
  ,[NAME]
  ,[LOCATION]
  ,[COMMENT]
FROM table1
WHERE PROJECT_ID = 4479
```

but this one doesn't:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[PROJECT_ID]
  ,[NAME]
  ,[LOCATION]
  ,[COMMENT]
FROM table1
WHERE PROJECT_ID = 3560
```

It spins and spins indefinitely. The only difference is the value used.

"PROJECT_ID" is a foreign key, and there is an index defined with it as the sole column (per usual with FKs).

In parallel: there is high fragmentation on the FK indexes on this table.

Are these probably related, ie, if I rebuild indexes should I expect the problem will be fixed?

I cannot rebuild them now as it is a production system and my understanding is I can only rebuild indexes when locks can be obtained... such as late tonight.

Any guidance on how to "force a rebuild of all indexes in all tables in a database even if it disconnects users" is also appreciated.

Thanks,
- Jesse

Comment: I have confirmed that rebuilding the indexes did indeed fix my problem, once I figured out how to drop blocking connections/sessions in order to do the rebuild by right-clicking "Indexes" in SSMS. Thanks.

Comment: You can at least run online index reorganization during the day so that at night there is less work to do during a rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Are those queries encapsulated in a stored procedure?  If so, you might be getting hit by parameter sniffing.

You might also check your statistics; it's possible that if they are very much out of date you could be getting a very poor execution plan with certain parameters and not with others.

Comment: And if selectivity is quite volatile (or the table is so large that keeping statistics up to date manually is like draining the ocean with a cup), you might want to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query, to thwart parameter sniffing.

Comment: Thank you. It wasn't SP related but it was definitely at least Stats related if not Index (not sure because both are done on a rebuild is my understanding.)